# email уведомления при изменении в колонке google таблицы

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

Есть Гугл таблица с колонкой Q, о любом изменении в которой нужно получать уведомления на email. Создан триггер on edit и запущен скрипт ниже, но он уведомляет о любых изменения во всей таблице. В чем может быть проблема со скриптом?

```
function sendNotification() {
     var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
     var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet();
     var cell = ss.getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
     var row = sheet.getActiveRange().getRow();
     var cellvalue = ss.getActiveCell().getValue().toString();
     var recipients = "aaa@gmail.com";
     var message = '';
     if(cell.indexOf('Q')!=-1)
     var subject = 'Update to '+sheet.getName();
     var body = sheet.getName() + ' has been updated. Visit ' + ss.getUrl() + ' to view the changes on row: «' + row + '». New comment: «' + cellvalue + '». For message: «' + message + '»';
     MailApp.sendEmail(recipients, subject, body);
};
```

Comment: на Stack Overflow на русском вопросы принято задавать **только на русском языке**. Пожалуйста, переведите ваш вопрос на русский язык или воспользуйтесь Stack Overflow на английском.

Answer (score 0):

Создайте функцию onEdit() и внутри нее уже стройте логику

Comment: пожалуйста, оставляйте чуть более развёрнутые ответы. [постарайтесь рассказать обо всех нюансах, которые могут возникнуть при решении проблемы по вашему сценарию. изложите свои предложения. возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]